# C++ - Program returning values without return statement

Tags: c++

I have this small question on functions in C++

```
#include <iostream>

int multiply(int x, int y)
{
    int product = x * y;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << multiply(4,90) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code produces output 360. Ok maybe this is an error. I changed the values. 
And the output changed accordingly. I agree that the code should not give a compilation error. But how is the function returning values without having a return statement.

Compiler: GNU GCC 5.1
Compile statement: g++ file.cpp

No compilation flags were used.

Now this was just for testing. The problem is in this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct tree{
    int data;
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
};
typedef struct tree *node;
node getNode(){
    node n = (node)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    n->data = 0;
}
int main(){
    node root = getNode();
    root->data = 4;
    std::cout << root->data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles. Okay agreed. Produces a warning that getNode() doesn't return anything. That's okay, I must get a runtime error. But the code produces the following output successfully.

```
4
```

How? How did the 'root' get assigned to a node that was created by another function but not returned by it?

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. It does not mean that the code won't work. It means that it can do anything.

Comment: Next time, compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. **Use the debugger** `gdb`.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. It can do anything. Sometimes it does what it was meant to do by accident.

Comment: g++ -Wall.... charming!!! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But how is the function returning values without having a return statement?

```
_Z8multiplyii:
.LFB1486:
    .cfi_startproc
    push    rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    mov rbp, rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-24], esi
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]           <--- look here
    imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]       <--- and here
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
    nop
    pop rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

That's what your function compiles to without optimisations on GCC 6. It simply uses `eax` to store the result, and that's why it works (the EAX registry is treated as the result value under this call convention). The `-O2` version returns 0, as it is fully entitled to do because of the undefined behaviour (and in a pretty funny way at that):

```
_Z8multiplyii:
.LFB1511:
    .cfi_startproc
    rep ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

The well-formed version differs only slightly, and makes it even easier to see why your code works:

```
...
mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax         <--- compare this
mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]         <--- and this
...
```

---

I haven't touched the more complex ("actual") code, but it's nearly the same there, except it's `call malloc` which gets stored into `rax`, and then the field setters leave it there.

```
sub rsp, 16
mov edi, 24
call    malloc                     <--- result stored in rax

mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax         <--- struct field setting here
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
mov QWORD PTR [rax+8], 0
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
mov QWORD PTR [rax+16], 0
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]         <--- rax contains proper pointer at the end
mov DWORD PTR [rax], 0

nop
leave
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret                                <--- which is then left for return
.cfi_endproc
```

Comment: And how do you compile without optimizations? I mean any specific flags that you used?

Comment: @Sushant I used no options and `-O2` for no opts and opts, respectively. `-S -masm=intel` for assembly output.

Comment: @Sushant `-O0` would force no optimisation, but should not be needed, as you should not get into a situation where you end up with earlier `-O` flags in the command line. `-Og` means 'optimise a bit, but try to avoid anything that would hinder debugging'.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is, at its core, a very low level language. The values your function handles get put into stack and registers, and remain there until they're overwritten. The same stack space and registers get re-used all the time, and if you have program which contains *undefined behavior*, it's quite possible that next computation ends up using the same data already there.

Now in this case, the compiler generates code to do your computations, and leaves the results there. You don't return them, but they happen to be in the same memory locations in stack, or in the same registers, which would be used if you did return something. And the calling code doesn't know the function didn't return anything, it just trusts the function signature, and takes return value (according to the used *calling convention*, if you want to google that).

But if you turned on optimizations, compiler might actually remove your computations entirely, and then you would get garbage results. Or the whole program might just crash. Or something else, that is what "undefined" means.

Also if you added more code to your functions, or changed them in any way, then the result might get stored in different location, and you would get something else as "return value". Or the whole program might just crash. Or something else, that is what "undefined" means.

---

This is why you want to

- enable warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` is good for *gcc* and *clang*, for example).
- fix them, so you ideally get 0 warnings from your code.

Of course no warnings is no guarantee that there isn't any nasty undefined behavior, but it will help you to avoid the most common cases.